# Compare strings in array with another string

Tags: objective-c, arrays, ios

I would like to know how to compare a string with an array, i.e., if my array list has `{"abc", "pqr", "xyz"}` and the new string lets say `"mno"` is typed, it should compare with my previous array list. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the NSArray documentation...

```
BOOL hasString = [your_array containsObject:your_string];
```

Comment: can we use it in if condition

Comment: @sameer, yes you can: `if ([your_array containsObject:your_string]) {}`

Comment: This is only a good solution if you are not interested in the actual string contents - which is usually not the case. The containsObject call uses isEquals to compare each item.

Comment: @crow, you're the only one that took this into account. I was actually looking for a way to invoke isEqualToString in a similar way, but later realised that isEqual is enough for me in current scenario.
However, I'm interested in a clean solution with isEqualToString, just out of curiosity. Do you know how we can achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

System:

```
if ([yourArray containsObject:yourNSString])
{
    NSLog(@"Bingo!");
}
```

Manual:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < [yourArray count] ; i++) {
    if ([yourNSString isEqualToString:[yourArray objectAtIndex:i]]) {
        NSLog(@"Bingo!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0; i<[myarray length]; ++i) {
     if([myarray[i] isEqualToString:@"mno"])
            NSLog("Equal");
     else NSLog("Not Equal");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working (tested) method,

```
-(BOOL)checkStingInArray: (NSString *)aString arrayWithStrings:(NSMutableArray *)array

{

    if ( [array containsObject: aString] ) {

        NSLog(@" %@ found in Array",aString );
        return YES;

    } else {
        NSLog(@" %@ not found in Array",aString );
        return NO;
    }
}
```